# Tricky PHP/Mysql date calculation

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date such as `2009-06-30` (30th june, 2009). I want to calculate a date which appears 2 months, and 3 days before or after the first date. Or, 3 months, 6 days, before or after, etc. How can I do this? Is there an easy way using `DATE_SUB()` or `DATE_ADD()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATE_ADD(whatever, INTERVAL 2 MONTH) + INTERVAL 3 DAY` for example (just to show both of the syntax variants you can use in MySQL for this task) will give a date that's 2 months and 3 days after `whatever`.

Comment: Awesome. Do I need to be particular about whether I add/subtract the days before the months or not, etc? Or will it calculate the same date in the end?

Comment: No guarantees: `select '2009-01-30' - interval 1 day + interval 1 month` says 2009-02-28, but `select '2009-01-30' + interval 1 month - interval 1 day;` says 2009-02-27. "Adding N months" is not a clearly defined mathematical operation, since months are of different lengths, so there's some "fuzzy maths" there;-).

Answer (score 0):

[Zend_Date](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.html) is great for this kind of thing.  Zend_Date is part of the Zend_Framework, and you can just use the Zend_Date part, you don't have to use the whole part of the framework.

You can add days or months to a date and it will handle all the complexities for you.  It's much easier than any other method I've found in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [DateTime:sub](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php).  To get the date 3 months and six days you should be able to use:

```
date_sub($myDate,"P3M6D");
```